# Can property wrapper have default parameter values?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to implement property wrapper that is initialized by either explicit values or predefined defaults? So that, given example:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct Wrapper<Value> {
    private(set) var value: Value!

    private var x: Int
    private var y: Int

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue }
    }

    init(wrappedValue value: Value,
         withX x: Int = 10,
         withY y: Int = 20) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.wrappedValue = value
    }
}
```

is able to be initialized in any of the following ways

```swift
@Wrapper
var allDefaults = ...

@Wrapper(withX: 30)
var explicitX = ...

@Wrapper(withY: 40)
var explicitY = ...

@Wrapper(withX: 50, withY: 60)
var allExplicit = ...
```

The above example works in *swift 5.1* only in case all of the optional parameters are explicitly initialized, as in last @Wrapper example. 
In any other case this results in `error: Abort trap: 6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a compiler bug that has been resolved: [SR-11480](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11480)